# How to change separator in CoffeeScript generator?

Tags: coffeescript

Following code:

```
yearsOld = max: 10, ida: 9, tim: 11

ages = for child, age of yearsOld
  "#{child} is #{age}"
```

will return:

```
max is 10, ida is 9, tim is 11
```

How to make it return a value without commas? Like that:

```
max is 10 ida is 9 tim is 11
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no "commas" in `ages`.

`ages` is an array, and if you write an array to the console, the default behavior is to display it with commas. If you don't want commas, you can use `Array#join` produce a string separating the values with whatever separator you want:

```
yearsOld = max: 10, ida: 9, tim: 11

ages = for child, age of yearsOld
  "#{child} is #{age}"

agesString = ages.join ' '

console.log agesString
```

Answer (score 1):

**c.coffee**

```
yearsOld = max: 10, ida: 9, tim: 11

ages = (input)->
  output=""
  for k,v of input
    output += k + " is " + v + " "
  return output

console.log ages yearsOld
```

run

```
coffee c.coffee
max is 10 ida is 9 tim is 11
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a "one-liner":

**c.coffee**

```
yearsOld = max: 10, ida: 9, tim: 11

console.log  (("#{k} is #{v}") for k, v of yearsOld).join(' ')
```

run

```
coffee c.coffee
max is 10 ida is 9 tim is 11
```

If you want to filter, for example not including ida:

```
console.log ((("#{k} is #{v}") if k != "ida") for k, v of yearsOld ).join(' ').replace('  ', ' ').replace(/^\s/, '')
```

or only above 10 years old:

```
console.log ((("#{k} is #{v}") if v > 10) for k, v of yearsOld ).join(' ').replace('  ', ' ').replace(/^\s/, '')
```